# how do I set my Audio Session Default Behavior to Playback in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio

My app has a "Click" sound functionality. I used the

```
import AVFoundation
```

then the following function to run the "Click" sound:

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func playSound() {
    var soundPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("tick", ofType: "wav")
    var soundURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(soundPath!)
    self.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL, error: nil)
    self.audioPlayer.play()
}
```

Now if the user is running a music player, my app causes the music player to stop. I read about the Audio Session Default Behavior in the documentation, but I don't know how to apply it.

Can you please help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are wondering the syntax for swift 2, here it is:

```
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions: .DuckOthers)
    } catch {
        print("AVAudioSession cannot be set: \(error)")
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Swift 2.0 error handling using do catch is still a new concept to me and you spelled it out here perfectly. Much appreciated.

Comment: I think you should setActive for the session here? ref: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swift/how-to-set-avaudio-session-correctly/2542

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you want the app to behave, i.e, how your app's sound effect or music should interact with other app's background audio session, you might need to tweak both the audio session category and categoryOption.

If you just want to play the sound effect, like "tick" sound, then, AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient and DuckOthers should be used respectively, for example:

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, withOptions: .DuckOthers, error: error)
```

However, I suppose you are actually trying to play a sound effect, in this case, the AudioServices API is a more suitable choice. You can check func AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(inSystemSoundID: SystemSoundID) in AudioToolbox framework for more details.

Another common scenario. If you want to have your app to play audio exclusively, even if there're other app's playing the music in the background, you need to set the category to AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient, for example:

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient, error: error)
```

I hope you've got what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer utogaria, I added a line of missing code in the question above. I don't know if it would make a difference, but I don't have much experience to understand where and how to put in your code, is there a simpler explanation on where and how to apply those code?